# chat client using Openfire, Javascript (strophe.js), and html5 websockets?

Tags: javascript, html, xmpp, websocket, openfire

I want to build a XMPP web-based chat client to add on to outlook web access.  I've read that Javascript is problematic.

Could I use html5 websockets using the openfire server and the Javascript(strophe)?

I've read on other solutions that include using flxHR, a flash library.
Which would be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of the WebSocket libraries, technologies and services provide fallback for browsers that don't support WebSockets. This is generally done via Flash but some libraries also fallback to HTTP streaming or polling.

Have a search for WebSockets on the following page for available technologies:
http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-technologies-guide

Answer (score 1):

Just use an existing XMPP/BOSH library for JavaScript, such as [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/).  You don't need to wait for WebSockets.